# hadoop yarn: show the pending resoure request of an application

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How could I get the number of pending requests sent to the resource manager by an application? As I know, the resource manager may not allocate the requested resources immediately, so requests will be pended, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Hadoop 2.7.1. From the Resource Manager UI, you can see the "Outstanding Resource Requests".

In the RM UI:

1. Click on the running application (for e.g. application_1447644421851_0004)
2. In the application page, click on the attempt ID (for e.g. appattempt_1447644421851_0004_000001)
3. In the Application Attempt ID page, you'll see the details of "**Total Allocated Containers**" and "**Total Outstanding Resource Requests**".

For e.g., I ran a DistCp job, which needed 24 mappers. So, total containers allocated were 24 + 1 (1 container for Application Master) = 25.

As per my settings, each container needed 1,228 MB of memory and 1 vCore.

I have explained the progress of this job with the pictures below:

**Stage 1:**

To begin with 7 mappers started running and totally 8 containers were allotted (7 for mappers and 1 for Application Master).

So,

`Total Allocated Containers: 8`
`Total Outstanding Requests: <memory: 20876, vCores:17>`

You can observe that, there are outstanding requests for 17 containers (25 minus 8). So total outstanding request for memory is = 17 * 1228 MB = 20876 MB and for vCores it is = 17 * 1 = 17

Check the picture below:
[image]

**Stage 2:**

7 mappers completed and next 7 were scheduled.

Now:

`Total Allocated Containers: 15`
`Total Outstanding Requests: <memory: 12280, vCores:10>`

You can observe that, outstanding requests has now come down to 10 containers (25 minus 15). So total outstanding requests for memory is = 10 * 1228 MB = 12280 MB and for vCores it is = 10 * 1 = 10

Check the picture below:

[image]

**Stage 3:**

14 mappers completed and next 7 were scheduled.

Now:

`Total Allocated Containers: 22`
`Total Outstanding Requests: <memory: 3684, vCores:3>`

You can observe that, outstanding requests has come down to 3 containers (25 minus 22). So total outstanding request for memory is = 3 * 1228 MB = 3684 MB and for vCores it is = 3 * 1 = 3

Check the picture below:

[image]

**Final Stage:**

Finally, when all the containers were allocated, you will just see "**Total Allocated Containers**".

Check the picture below:

[image]

Hope this clarified your doubt.

Comment: Thank you Manjunath. Can we get it from the command line, rather than go to the Web UI?

Comment: At present, you cannot get these details from the CLI. I checked all the options in the "YARN CLI". For application report, it just shows, for e.g.: "Aggregate Resource Allocation : 6788227 MB-seconds, 5518 vcore-seconds". It does not show the details of the allocated and pending resources.

Comment: What about using REST API? Can we write something like a shell script to get this info. I am new to yarn. Can we get the info from analyzing some yarn commands or REST API by writing a script? Or try to grep it from the Web UI using some technique?

Comment: Yes, I think you can use REST APIs to get this information. But, I have never tried before. CLI outputs only a limited information. Whatever information present in UI, could be queried using REST end points.

Comment: Hi Manjunath, can you send a copy of your app running above to me if it is not confident? my email: zhubenqiang gmail com

Comment: No. I do not have any app. I suggested, it is possible to use REST endpoints to query the information, which is shown on the UI.

Comment: Actually, I went through the REST API. The info of the app attempt response is quite a little, nothing is given about the details on the Web UI

Comment: I will check. If I find something, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the container info and much more from YARN API endpoint

```
http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/metrics
```

Please visit at below resource to get more details

```
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Metrics_API
```